# convert data modis EVI to date yy-mm-dd in r

Tags: r, string, datetime, parsing, r-modis

I work with MODIS EVI rasters in 2000. I have 6 raster by years, one raster by month :

```
"D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000209_aid0001.tif"
"D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000225_aid0001.tif"
"D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000241_aid0001.tif"
"D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000257_aid0001.tif"
"D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000273_aid0001.tif"
"D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000289_aid0001.tif"
"D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000305_aid0001.tif"
"D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000321_aid0001.tif"
"D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000337_aid0001.tif"
"D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000353_aid0001.tif"
```

I would like convert the month like that 2000-02-09 but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @[loula-melyacou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10772852/loula-melyacou), are you sure that your data is having 7 digits instead of 8 (`2000209` in stead of `20000209`)? It would be easy to do for the later case.

Comment: yes only 7 digits 2000209 ! what i can do ?

Comment: @massisenergy 2000209 datimes is 27 jul 2000

Comment: Can you provide few more lines from your dataset, as `minimum working example [MWE]`? Check this: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @massisenergy yes i edited my question when i show more my dataset

Comment: Check if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `datetime` string format follows `year(4digits)day_of_year(3digit)` format, e.g. 2000209 means 2000 year & 209 days (27th July 2000). If it's true then the problem isn't difficult:

- Extract those seven digit numbers. (str_extract)
- Parse 'datetime' from it. (you need to know that `j` is used for parsing date from the `day_of_year`.)
- [:Graph:] will drop anything other than numbers and punctuation marks.

**Code**

```
dt <- data.frame(string =
     c("D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000209_aid0001.tif",
       "D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000225_aid0001.tif",
       "D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000241_aid0001.tif",
       "D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000257_aid0001.tif",
       "D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000273_aid0001.tif",
       "D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000289_aid0001.tif",
       "D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000305_aid0001.tif",
       "D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000321_aid0001.tif",
       "D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000337_aid0001.tif",
       "D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS/MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000353_aid0001.tif"))

dt$string %>% str_extract('\\d{7}') %>% str_replace('2000', '2000-') %>% 
   parse_date_time('y-j') %>% str_subset('[:graph:]')
```

**Output**

> [1] "2000-07-27" "2000-08-12" "2000-08-28" "2000-09-13" "2000-09-29" "2000-10-15"
>   [7] "2000-10-31" "2000-11-16" "2000-12-02" "2000-12-18"